# Instead of popups, output alerts, notices, tips to running log box on PHP form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a PHP form used to fill in product details, such as weight, dimensions, product information, etc. I would like to put a small box (textarea?) in the bottom right-hand corner where there is a running log of any alerts, tips or notices that will appear during the form filling.

For example, let's say dimensions are added that are above a certain size, I would like a notice to appear in the box that says "Hey, this is an oversized box so dimensional weight will be used to calculate shipping costs." And if there is another notice, it would appear under that one, like a scrolling log.

Should I use a textarea for this? How do I add additional notices without overwriting the previous ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of comments, I solved the problem as follows:

First, in form HTML, I created a DIV for the log that will scroll...

```
<div id="scanlog" style="white-space: pre-line; padding:10px;height:275px;width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;border:10px solid #666;overflow:auto;"></div>
```

...and where needed, include Javascript to add to the existing log with line breaks.

```
$('#scanlog').text("\nDVD Selected\n"+$('#scanlog').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when they correct the size and it stops being oversized? should that notice disappear? If so then for every onBlur, do a check and report all 'issues'.

I'd do this in JavaScript/JQuery. Textarea not needed, just use any block tag.

Comment: I figured for now just have it add one line after another like a running log that keep scrolling up and just have it state "Great, your package size is small, which is great for USPS, just not for your dates." To add a line, do I just take the original value+new value?

Comment: $('#messages').text("Wrong SIze Package"+$('#messages').text());